# Azure App Insights Debug Snapshot doesn't show Locals and Variables

Tags: azure, debugging, snapshot, telemetry, appinsights

We enabled Snapshot Debugger on a QA environment. It seems to be collecting telemetry data, but it doesn't collect the Locals and Variables from the error location. I can think of a couple of hints to help in answering this question:

1. We do not copy any `.pdb` files to QA environment
2. It worked perfectly fine on dev machines, but it doesn't work the same in QA environment.

These are a few things I thought of that could effect the telemetry and I'll try to update if I find more.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, it is the absence of the .pdb symbol files when the site was deployed in QA environment that caused AI telemetry not being able to collect Local Variable data.
We tested it on a different environment with no symbol files included in the deployment. As expected, the AI telemetry failed to load Locals. But on same environment, this time with .pdb symbol files, telemetry way able to collect enough local variables and create a debug snapshot dump in AI.
This helped me, hope it helps others trying to integrate AI Snapshot Debugger into their apps